# Download full article from Inoreader RSS

Tags: python, api, rss

I am using Inoreader API for scraping articles,but for many RSS feeds it returns a small summary of articles. Any idea how to take the whole context??

Comment: An RSS doc would typically have a `<link>` to whatever it refers to. Can you post an example of one that is causing problems?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.